# AVPlayer music stops when going to other view

Tags: swift, xcode, avplayer, avaudioplayer, internet-radio

im making a radio app and I have a swrevealviewcontroller with 3 views 
picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qnmz.png)

this is the code of my first view, in trying to play music from a link with AVPlayer. 
code:

I can start and stop the music from playing with this code but
when I open the menu and click on a menulink my music stops playing.

I cannot find a solution for this, I have already added the bacground mode in capability.

btw every view controller already has one class assigned to it.

can somoene pls help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AVPlayer variable is located within the class.  So when you leave that viewcontroller - that variable no longer exists.  Make it global (outside of the class) and that should work just fine.

Comment: thx its works fine when going from the first view to the second or third one but when going from those to the first when it stops playing, is their a way to fix that ? :)

Answer (score 0):

everything is working now by adding the player and the functions outside of the class, so now it's a global player with functions to start and play it

Comment: just deleted the pictures with it